# Orbit Equation of a particle moving under a central force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservative-field

I want to prove that the orbit of a particle of mass $m$ that is moving under a central force $\vec{F}=f(r)\hat{r}$ is given by the differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}-\frac{2}{r}(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2-r=\frac{mr^4}{l^2}f(r)$$ where $l$ is the value of the angular momentum.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a conservative force $\vec{F}(r)=-\nabla V(r)$. Using Lagrangian Mechanics. You can also use the chain rule to change which variable you are differentiating by. This process gives you the expected elliptical motion in the case of an inverse square law force.

The Lagrangian.
$\Lambda=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2+\frac{1}{2}mr^2\dot{\theta}^2-V(r)$.

The corresponding Euler-Lagrange Equations:

$m\ddot{r}-mr\dot{\theta}^2+\partial V /\partial r=0$.

$mr^2\dot{\theta}=l. $

$\ddot{r}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{dr}{d\theta})$

$m\ddot{r}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{r^2}mr^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{dr}{d\theta})$

$m\ddot{r}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta})=\frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta})=\dot{\theta}(\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}-\frac{2l}{r^3}(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2)$

So:

$\dot{\theta}(\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}-\frac{2l}{r^3}(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2)=mr\dot{\theta}^2+F(r)$

$(\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}-\frac{2l}{r^3}(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2)=mr\dot{\theta}+F(r)/\dot{\theta}$

$(\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}-\frac{2}{r}(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2)=mr^3\dot{\theta}/l+r^2F(r)/l\dot{\theta}$

$\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}-\frac{2}{r}(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2=r+mr^4F(r)/l^2$